# IIS rewrite rule to redirect to new domain with query string value passed

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

I'm unable to figure out the IIS url rewrite rule, hopefully someone can help. I want to create a redirect rule (302-found)

from:

domain1.com/?kb=**8**

to:

domain2.com/view/**8**

Thank you.

Comment: I have a rule that seems to be parsing properly but it's not redirecting for some reason:

`<rule name="Redirect kb query">
    <match url="(.*)\?kb=\d+" />
    <conditions>
        <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="kb=(\d+)" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2.com/View/{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Found" />
</rule>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
<rule name="test" stopProcessing="true">   
  <match url="(.*)" />  
    <conditions>  
      <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="domain1.com" />  
      <add input="{QUERY_STRING}" pattern="kb=(.*)" />  
    </conditions>  
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://domain2.com/view/{C:1}" />  
</rule>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Sorry, I modified the rule, please try again.

Comment: Thank you, I was able to slightly modify this and make it work. I changed {HTTP_HOST} to (.*) and added appendQueryString="false" and redirectType="Found"